# SQL division returns NULL value instead of Numeric

Tags: mysql, sql, null, sum, average

I am looking to calculate daily revenue from the data-set below. When there is a 0 that means the asset was not producing revenue and should not be included into the daily revenue calculation. Instead of retrieving a numeric daily revenue, I am returned with a NULL value. The following is my code and the data-set.

```
    **asset_revenue**
          15
          15
          213
          0
          32
          89
          -47

          SUM([asset_revenue]) / SUM(CASE WHEN asset_revenue <> 0 THEN 7 ELSE NULL END)
```

In the example above, I am expecting the daily revenue to be 7.54. Is there a reason why SQL is returning a NULL value?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are trying to get an average.

Just use `0` instead of `NULL`. This will result in your denominator equaling the number of rows that have a non-zero `asset_revenue`.

If the rows represent daily revenue:

```
SELECT SUM([asset_revenue]) / 
    CASE
        WHEN SUM([asset_revenue]) <> 0 THEN SUM(CASE WHEN asset_revenue <> 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
        ELSE 1 -- Special case where asset_revenue is zero across the entire time period. 0/1 is still zero, so that represents an average revenue of zero.
    END
```

If the rows represent weekly revenue or if the `7` needs to be retained for some other reason, do this:

```
SELECT SUM([asset_revenue]) /
    CASE
        WHEN SUM([asset_revenue]) <> 0 THEN SUM(CASE WHEN asset_revenue <> 0 THEN 7 ELSE 0 END)
        ELSE 1 -- Special case where asset_revenue is zero across the entire time period. 0/1 is still zero, so that represents an average revenue of zero.
    END
```

@Strawberry is correct as to the *reason* that your script returns `NULL`. `NULL` means you don't know what the value *is*. If you don't know what a value is, you can't know what happens when that unknown value is put into an arithmetic operation and the result is requested. What is 55 plus some unknown value? I don't know!

Comment: Thanks for the assistance. However, I need to use 7 to incorporate the number of days.

Comment: You're very welcome. I updated my answer. However, I think `1` might be correct here because the denominator *sums* 1 for each day in which the `asset_revenue` is nonzero. That means that if there is revenue on each day, the result will come out to be 7 - the sum of 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1.

Comment: I tried that and I got the following error: Divide by zero error encountered.

Comment: The figures in column A are weekly revenue so I need to divide by 7.

Comment: Are you doing it for a set of days where there is no asset revenue at all? You need to special case that to avoid dividing by zero.

Comment: @Pandoo thanks, I thought you were saying they represented daily revenue. That makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

Reason:

```
SELECT 1 + NULL;
+----------+
| 1 + NULL |
+----------+
|     NULL |
+----------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Answer (score 0):

In some situations the `COALESCE` function is handy:

```
mysql> SELECT COALESCE(123, 1), COALESCE(NULL, 1);
+------------------+-------------------+
| COALESCE(123, 1) | COALESCE(NULL, 1) |
+------------------+-------------------+
|              123 |                 1 |
+------------------+-------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

More specifically:

```
SUM(asset_revenue) /
   COALESCE(SUM(CASE WHEN asset_revenue <> 0 THEN 7 ELSE NULL END), 0)
```

or maybe

```
COALESCE( SUM(asset_revenue) /
          SUM(CASE WHEN asset_revenue <> 0 THEN 7 ELSE NULL END)
         1)
```

For brevity:

```
SUM(CASE WHEN asset_revenue <> 0 THEN 7 ELSE NULL END)
```

-->

```
7 * SUM(asset_revenue <> 0)
```

(Except that it can yield 0 instead of NULL)